# How to make very dark photos brighter?

Tags: editing

I took photos of the full moon but they all turned out black.
I recognize my mistake later where my shutter speed was 4000, the aperture was f/11, and the iso was 100.

My question is how to make the photos clear and bright?

Comment: You very probably don't… however, posting one of the images may help diagnosis/confirmation. If you were shooting RAW, then you'll need to post to an external site we could look at. If jpg, then you can post to here. BTW your camera settings were more appropriate to capturing fast action in bright sunlight, so hopes are [very] low.

Comment: The lunar surface would be "only" about five stops underexposed at ISO 100, f/11 and 1/4000.  If you were shooting moonlit landscape, you were under by another half dozen stops and almost every bin on your sensor had *zero* in it.  But welcome to Photography Stack Exchange, anyway!  Please take the [tour] and read through the [FAQ] -- we recommend that for all our new members.

Comment: @Tetsujin A user with a rep of 1 can't post any kind of photo here. JPEG or raw would have to be linked to an image hosting site.

Comment: They can post but not inline it. I inline several a day on other stacks for newbies. Sure, a larger file would need to be hosted elsewhere [as I mentioned] & linked from here, in a comment or an edit.

Comment: @Tetsujin How might one post an image directly to a question *without* "inlining" (*i.e.* embedding) it? They can include a link, but that's not posting a photo, that's providing a link.

Comment: @MichaelC - Newbies can upload to i.imgur same as anyone [though limited numbers] but it shows the image link, it doesn't visually inline it. Markdown for newbies is `[enter image description here][1]` which shows only as a link, as opposed to `[![enter image description here][1]][1]` which inlines the actual image.

Comment: Uploading to imgur is not the same as uploading to SE. That's my entire point. It's just a link, rather than an embedded image.

Comment: Then, if someone else edits the question to embed it, occasionally we get the complaint that they didn't want the image embedded because of the terms of use.